# getpos() coding

Tags: python

just wanted to know how to write the getpos() command which must return an (x,y) tuple of the current position.

does it start like this:

```
def getpos(x 100, y 100)
```

not sure need help

Comment: start here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit underspecified, but this might work:

```
def getpos(self):
  return (self.x, self.y)
```

This is how to return a tuple, from values assumed to be instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can't force a return type on a function from its header. The return type can change from one call to another.
When you write:

```
def getpos(x,y):
```

It means that the function receives 2 parameters, that inside the function are called x & y. No type is forced on them either.
Just write the function so it returns the tuple, e.g.:

```
def getpos():
    x = 100
    y = 100
    return (x,y)
```

The syntax that you used (def getpos(x 100, y 100) ) does not have any meaning that I know.